# Edit & Update a record in Data grid View

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2005

i'm trying to update my data in datagridview by going to sqldatasource properties "update queries" and writing the codes but its showing an error message

"Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_contact_master'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.admission_table'.
The statement has been terminated. "

plz tell me the exact code of editing the data in datagridview and update it..

Thanks,
Churchill

UPDATE:

Sql Code:

```
Update admission_table 
set registration_id=@registration_id,
name_of_degree=@name_of_degree,
fees_paid=@fees_paid,
hostel=@hostel,
hostel_fees=@hostel_fees,
name_of_student=@name_of_student,
Dat­e_of_birth=@Date_of_birth,
nationality=@nationality,
gender=@gender,
address=@addres­s,
phone_no=@phone_no,
e_mail=@e_mail,
date=@date
```

Comment: Show us exactly what code you have now and maybe we will.

Comment: Update admission_table set registration_id=@registration_id,name_of_degree=@name_of_degree,fees_paid=@fees_paid,hostel=@hostel,hostel_fees=@hostel_fees,name_of_student=@name_of_student,Date_of_birth=@Date_of_birth,nationality=@nationality,gender=@gender,address=@address,phone_no=@phone_no,e_mail=@e_mail,date=@date

Comment: registration_id column  is the primary key of my table and after equals to the @registration_id is the name of my table column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the sql query you provided it seems like your issue is that you don't have a where clause on your update query and you appear to be setting the primary key in the update.

This means you will update every record in the table with the same info and violate the PK.

To fix this I would first add a where clause.  Once you are updating only the record you want you can most likely remove the `registration_id` from your set clause (assuming that's your pk).

Comment: Well thank u so much i have fixed up my problem....and its working perfectly..thank_u